# How frequently does the Android OS itself (not apps) poll for Location?

Tags: android, location

I'm looking at writing a location-aware application for Android.  My application would periodically make calls to a central server, passing in the current user's location.  I don't want to drain the battery, so I've been considering using the `Passive` Location Provider.

According to the provider description no active polling is performed (hence being labelled "Passive").  Instead, it relies on other applications requesting active polls.

My question is:  If no other applications poll for Location, does it mean the `Passive` provider never provides any data?  Or, does the Android OS itself periodically poll for Location.  If so, what is the polling frequency?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Google Play Services Location API](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html). Its fused location provider will relieve you from such concerns. Forget about which providers to use, or how often the location is polled, or if there are other apps polling. Instead, specify high-level needs like "high accuracy" or "low power", and at which interval your app should be notified. Use listeners or intents to receive location updates from the location service. Here's a [more recent article with some code](http://www.kpbird.com/2013/06/fused-location-provider-example.html).

Comment: The concern of the question is battery. This answer would drain battery more than existing code of the questioner.

Comment: @siva As the OP stated in his question, he's "looking at writing a location-aware application", so It seems he has not written any code. Even if he did, it is probably at early stages of development, a very appropriate time to choose a higher level API, which is my advice. Also, I have not provided a single line of code, so how can you tell it drains more battery than some other hypothetical code?!?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Android OS will not poll for location itself. If some apps polls it you can received the location then. See [Android - Are there query-able services that already poll for GPS location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124142/android-are-there-query-able-services-that-already-poll-for-gps-location) .

If no app has polled for location from a long time, last location known might be returned by the passive provider. If your application relies heavily on the location, then you might actually want to poll it yourself or if nothing is returned by the passive provider then you can yourself get the location. Frequency of getting the location can be 5 minutes( which is suggested by Google in the Android documentation). This frequency can vary based on your app's requirement.

Is you read the android documentation of `requestLocationUpdates` of [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29), it says:

> Choosing a sensible value for minTime is important to conserve battery life. Each location update requires power from GPS, WIFI, Cell and other radios. Select a minTime value as high as possible while still providing a reasonable user experience. If your application is not in the foreground and showing location to the user then your application should avoid using an active provider (such as NETWORK_PROVIDER or GPS_PROVIDER), but if you insist then select a **minTime of 5 * 60 * 1000 (5 minutes)** or greater. If your application is in the foreground and showing location to the user then it is appropriate to select a faster update interval.

That's my 2 cents regarding your question.

Comment: The accepted answer for the question you linked references [an android blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html).  I'd be willing to accept that as an answer if it weren't so old.

Comment: @MetaFight Did you find anything odd in that answer which seems to be changed in the latest API versions?

Comment: Not from the quick look I took at it.  It's still over two years old.  Long enough for a constantly evolving API such as Android's to make some pretty drastic changes.

Answer (score -1):

Android devices themselves never poll for users location, you need to do it yourself or rely on other apps to do it for you. You can possibly run the location update every 'x' min, using a GPS or network provider whatever deems fit (or maybe even both !)

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1500000, 0, locationListener);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1500000, 0, locationListener);
```

If you want to wait for other applications, or not want to drain the battery/search for users exact location you may use  `locationManager.getLastLocation();`
This wont be always accurate, however it is the best you can hope for without actually running a location search

Comment: I the fact that the Android OS doesn't ever poll documented somewhere?

Comment: @MetaFight http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html states that all you need is to retrieve your current location which requires you to connect the location client and get the current location.

Comment: I know I'm being pedantic, but the link you provided doesn't actually state that the OS doesn't ever poll for location.  I'm looking for a definitive source.

Answer (score -1):

Though I don't believe that PASSIVE_LOCATION PROVIDERS will not get any location unless no other apps get a location, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110306/android-passive-location-provide) is some post which is evangelizing it.

I believe that there would be some resident services part of the OS itself which listen to location changed events. because location services without maps, generally use GPS. But I recommend you to have a look at [this discussion](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html) (probably trusted source).

Answer (score -1):

as none of the posts here answer the OP question i'll make my three words here -

1. **IT'S UP TO PROVIDER (TO PROVIDE THE LOCATION UPDATES) THUS PROVIDER DECIDES HOW OFTEN WILL REPORT THE LOCATION CHANGES TO LOCATON SERVICE**
2. **PASIVE - LIKE A PING PONG** - to understand what it mean study flow of bellow methods

   - getLastLocation(LocationRequest request, String packageName)
   - reportLocation(Location location, boolean passive) -> updateLastLocationLocked(...) -> handleLocationChangedLocked(...)
3. **ITS DEVELOPER JOB TO FILTER AND DECIDE IF PROVIDED LOCATION FULFILLS IT NEEDS**

ad 3/ see all location provied details like:

- PROVIDER NAME
- ACCURACY,
- TIME (MILLIS - EPOCH TIME),
- SYSTEM ELAPSED NANOS (ELAPSED NANOS FROM DEVICE START)
- ADDITIONAL DATA (EG IN BUNDLE LIKE SATELITES COUNT)
- ETC...

ad 2/ LOCATION SERVICE IMPLEMENTATION ON AOSP:

```
package com.android.server;

/**
 * The service class that manages LocationProviders and issues location
 * updates and alerts.
 */
public class LocationManagerService extends ILocationManager.Stub {

    ...

    // mapping from provider name to last known location
    private final HashMap<String, Location> mLastLocation = new HashMap<>();
    // same as mLastLocation, but is not updated faster than LocationFudger.FASTEST_INTERVAL_MS.
    // locations stored here are not fudged for coarse permissions.
    private final HashMap<String, Location> mLastLocationCoarseInterval = new HashMap<>();

   ...


    @Override
    public Location getLastLocation(LocationRequest request, String packageName) {

             ...

            // Figure out the provider. Either its explicitly request (deprecated API's),
            // or use the fused provider
            String name = request.getProvider();
            if (name == null) name = LocationManager.FUSED_PROVIDER;
            LocationProviderInterface provider = mProvidersByName.get(name);
            if (provider == null) return null;

            ...

            Location location;
            if (allowedResolutionLevel < RESOLUTION_LEVEL_FINE) {
                // Make sure that an app with coarse permissions can't get frequent location
                // updates by calling LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation repeatedly.
                location = mLastLocationCoarseInterval.get(name);
            } else {
                location = mLastLocation.get(name);
            }
            if (location == null) {
                return null;
            }
            if (allowedResolutionLevel < RESOLUTION_LEVEL_FINE) {
                Location noGPSLocation = location.getExtraLocation(Location.EXTRA_NO_GPS_LOCATION);
                if (noGPSLocation != null) {
                    return new Location(mLocationFudger.getOrCreate(noGPSLocation));
                }
            } else {
                return new Location(location);
            }
        }
        return null;
    ....

      private void handleLocationChangedLocked(Location location, boolean passive) {
            if (D) Log.d(TAG, "incoming location: " + location);
            long now = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            String provider = (passive ? LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER : location.getProvider());
            // Skip if the provider is unknown.
            LocationProviderInterface p = mProvidersByName.get(provider);
            if (p == null) return;
            updateLastLocationLocked(location, provider);
            // mLastLocation should have been updated from the updateLastLocationLocked call above.
            Location lastLocation = mLastLocation.get(provider);
            if (lastLocation == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "handleLocationChangedLocked() updateLastLocation failed");
                return;
            }
            // Update last known coarse interval location if enough time has passed.
            Location lastLocationCoarseInterval = mLastLocationCoarseInterval.get(provider);
            if (lastLocationCoarseInterval == null) {
                lastLocationCoarseInterval = new Location(location);
                mLastLocationCoarseInterval.put(provider, lastLocationCoarseInterval);
            }
            long timeDiffNanos = location.getElapsedRealtimeNanos()
                    - lastLocationCoarseInterval.getElapsedRealtimeNanos();
            if (timeDiffNanos > LocationFudger.FASTEST_INTERVAL_MS * NANOS_PER_MILLI) {
                lastLocationCoarseInterval.set(location);
            }
            // Don't ever return a coarse location that is more recent than the allowed update
            // interval (i.e. don't allow an app to keep registering and unregistering for
            // location updates to overcome the minimum interval).
            Location noGPSLocation =
                    lastLocationCoarseInterval.getExtraLocation(Location.EXTRA_NO_GPS_LOCATION);
            // Skip if there are no UpdateRecords for this provider.
            ArrayList<UpdateRecord> records = mRecordsByProvider.get(provider);
            if (records == null || records.size() == 0) return;
            // Fetch coarse location
            Location coarseLocation = null;
            if (noGPSLocation != null) {
                coarseLocation = mLocationFudger.getOrCreate(noGPSLocation);
            }
            // Fetch latest status update time
            long newStatusUpdateTime = p.getStatusUpdateTime();
            // Get latest status
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            int status = p.getStatus(extras);
            ArrayList<Receiver> deadReceivers = null;
            ArrayList<UpdateRecord> deadUpdateRecords = null;
            // Broadcast location or status to all listeners
            for (UpdateRecord r : records) {

            ...

            }

            ...
       }


          /**
           * Updates last location with the given location
           *
           * @param location             new location to update
           * @param provider             Location provider to update for
           */
          private void updateLastLocationLocked(Location location, String provider) {
              Location noGPSLocation = location.getExtraLocation(Location.EXTRA_NO_GPS_LOCATION);
              Location lastNoGPSLocation;
              Location lastLocation = mLastLocation.get(provider);
              if (lastLocation == null) {
                  lastLocation = new Location(provider);
                  mLastLocation.put(provider, lastLocation);
              } else {
                  lastNoGPSLocation = lastLocation.getExtraLocation(Location.EXTRA_NO_GPS_LOCATION);
                  if (noGPSLocation == null && lastNoGPSLocation != null) {
                      // New location has no no-GPS location: adopt last no-GPS location. This is set
                      // directly into location because we do not want to notify COARSE clients.
                      location.setExtraLocation(Location.EXTRA_NO_GPS_LOCATION, lastNoGPSLocation);
                  }
              }
              lastLocation.set(location);
          }
}
```

PASIVE PROVIDER:

```
/**
 * A passive location provider reports locations received from other providers
 * for clients that want to listen passively without actually triggering
 * location updates.
 *
 * {@hide}
 */
public class PassiveProvider implements LocationProviderInterface {

       ...

        @Override
        public void setRequest(ProviderRequest request, WorkSource source) {
            mReportLocation = request.reportLocation;
        }

        public void updateLocation(Location location) {
            if (mReportLocation) {
                try {
                    // pass the location back to the location manager
                    mLocationManager.reportLocation(location, true);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "RemoteException calling reportLocation");
                }
            }
        }

        ...
}
```